# 2 ActiveMQ Servers different versions same machine

Tags: activemq-classic

I want to know if it is possible to run 2 versions (5.5 and 5.10) of ActiveMQ on the same machine. I simply assume that all I need to do reconfigure the ports on one of them to something different to the other.

The reason for this is that we are using Informatica B2B which uses ActiveMQ @ 5.5 with a 3rd party (Fuse) addition for its internal messaging. We would also like to run a separate JMS server on the same machine for various reasons using 5.10 or 5.11.

I have found lots of examples of creating multiple instances, but they apply to using the same installation.

If it is that simple (as just changing the ports), can they also share the same JVM or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run multiple instances on the same machine by changing the ActiveMQ configuration.  You should assign each Broker a unique name and configure the transport connector to listen on different ports.  You also want to ensure that they are configure with different data directory instances and so on.

You cannot run two in the same JVN however.

Comment: Thanks for that, please ignore the last comment about same JVM (end of a long day)

Comment: I take it the default broker name of localhost is arbitary and not tied to the IP 127.0.0.0

Comment: Yes, it's just the default name, no relation to the actual localhost address.  You can assign it something more meaningful to your application / project.